# Is it possible to make a custom facet that behaves like a Views grouped filter?

Tags: views, search

I am moving my user search from vanilla Views to the [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api)/Solr backend/[Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) with Views.

On my site, I have a [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) field on the user profile, and I would like to give users the option to choose between two options: **from Japan** or **not from Japan**.

In Views, I did this using a grouped filter:

[image: views grouped filter]

Now I am trying to make a facet that does the same thing.  However, I don't think this is possible from the Facet UI, even with [Facet API Bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus) installed.  There appears to be no way to provide users with the choice of **A** or **NOT A** for a facet that has 100+ values.

How can I implement this **A** or **NOT A** search using the Facet API for a specific facet?

Comment: I recently had this on boolean value fields where the default was either "1" or "0" unless you set a label. This was for unique fields though with a facet for each, not ideal in your case as you would need a unique boolean checkbox on/off field for each country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://ygerasimov.com/add-custom-field-search-api-apachesolr-index), I was able to do this with the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['user']['properties']['agg_nat'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => t('Search API Agg Nationality'),
    'sanitized' => TRUE,
    'getter callback' => 'MYMODULE_search_agg_nat_getter_callback',
  );
}

/*
 * Getter callback for agg nationality property.
 */
function MYMODULE_search_agg_nat_getter_callback($item) {
  // Need to load the user object to get fields
  $account = user_load($item->uid);
  $nationality = $account->field_gen_nationality['und'][0]['iso2'];
  switch ($nationality) {
    case 'JP':
      return 'ja';
    break;
    default:
      return 'en';
    break;
  }
}
```